# Microservices with Karaf hot code replacement

Tags: rest, microservices, apache-karaf, hot-code-replace

I have a need to write a microservice and planning to use Karaf. I understand that Karaf is an OSGi based container for microservices to provide modularity. Now, my question is

Suppose I write a REST-based/ extends BundleActivator  service and deploy the Java code
As a bundle into Karaf. And say later when I make changes to service and deploy it again
Will it continue without any downtime? Will, it Hot deploy the java code/ module without any downtime?

Will it have support for one module to invoke another as an API/service call?

Thanks

Comment: Hot deployment will experience downtime.  But you can put a proxy in front of your service.  Then you can install a new version on another port, and then switch the port in the proxy without downtime.